# remove duplicate of a list in O(nlogn)

Tags: scheme, racket

How to remove duplicate of a list? (running time is O(n log n) )
ex: '(4 6 1 1 2 3 3 5 6) => '(4 6 1 2 3 5)

```
 (define (re-dup lst)
   (cond
      ((empty? lst) empty)
      (else
      (define el (first lst))
      (define el-free-lst (filter (lambda (x) (not (= el x))) (rest lst)))
      (cons el (re-dup el-free-lst)))))
```

Is this right?

Comment: No, this is traversing the list for each element (because of the `filter` procedure). It works correctly, but it's an `O(n^2)` solution

Comment: @ÓscarLópez then i'm confused. How to write a O(nlogn) or faster solution? Is it even possible?

Comment: see my answer for an `O(n)` solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current solution is `O(n^2)`, because `filter` traverses the list once *for each* of the elements in the original list. It's possible to write an `O(n)` solution using a helper data structure with constant time insertion and membership operations to keep track of the elements that have been found already.

In Racket, we have an out-of-the-box `set` data structure which, for *constant time operations*, "actually requires O(log N) time for a set of size N" (see the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fset..rkt%29._set-add%29%29)), therefore the `set-member?` and `set-add` procedures will be `O(log n)`. So this implementation using Racket's `set` is not optimal, but we achieve the `O(n log n)` target:

```
(define (re-dup lst)
  (let loop ((seen (set))
             (lst lst)
             (acc '()))
    (cond ((null? lst)
           (reverse acc))
          ((set-member? seen (car lst))
           (loop seen (cdr lst) acc))
          (else
           (loop (set-add seen (car lst))
                 (cdr lst)
                 (cons (car lst) acc))))))
```

It works as expected, preserving the original order in the list (which is a constraint for this problem, as stated in the comments) at the cost of one additional `O(n)` `reverse` operation:

```
(re-dup '(4 6 1 1 2 3 3 5 6))
=> '(4 6 1 2 3 5)
```

Comment: wouldn't it be O(n*log n) assuming set membership is O(log n)?

Comment: @Wes that's right. I'm not familiar with the underlying Racket implementation, but an optimal set data structure should be `O(1)` for the insertion and membership operations.

Comment: "set operations actually require O(log N) time for a set of size N." http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html#(def._((lib._racket/set..rkt)._set-member~3f))

I assume this is because the implementation uses some form of BST.

Comment: @Wes "Constant time" which is  `O(log N)`. Weird, I had overlooked that side note. I updated my answer, so I guess that using Racket's `set` we're stuck with an `O(n log n)` solution.

Comment: "a helper data structure with constant time insertion and membership operations" such a structure does not exist for general types

Comment: @newacct but for types with a good hash function it does exist, take a look at Java's [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) implementation which "offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets"

Comment: I think the reason it isn't using an implementation like that is that it's difficult to do in a purely functional manner.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: Lookup for hash tables have constant time *average case* performance, but linear time *worst case* performance. Saying "assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets" is like saying, "assuming we get the ideal inputs", which is not what algorithm complexity is all about.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `O(n log n)` behavior with the following:

1. Merge sort (which is `O(n log n)`)
2. Traverse and discard duplicates (which is `O(n)`

Thus overall `O(n log n)`.

```
(define (re-dup lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      lst
      (let ((lst (list-sort < lst)))
        (let thinning ((skip (car lst)) (rest (cdr lst)))
          (cond ((null? rest) (list skip))
                ((equal? skip (car rest)) (thinning skip (cdr rest)))
                (else (cons skip (thinning (car rest) (cdr rest)))))))))
```

Comment: If I do merge sort, the order of the list will be changed isn't it?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  That is a constraint?

Comment: You need to remove the duplicates, keeping the first or keeping the last?  For example `'(3 1 2 3)` => `'(3 1 2)` or `'(1 2 3)`

Comment: keeping the first '(3 1 2)

Comment: Then Oscar has got your answer!  (Well assuming you have a `set` implementation that is actually O(1) on `insert` and `find` - many are not).

Comment: For example: Scheme `member` is O(n); a poorly sized hashtable has worst case O(n); a TreeSet would be O(lg n); etc.

Comment: using a sort or a TreeSet would require an ordering on the elements, which would exist in this case for numbers, but not generally

Comment: "a poorly sized hashtable has worst case O(n)" *Any* hash table would have worst case O(n) for lookup