# Defining a Scheme Image function

Tags: scheme, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to define a function that takes two inputs and whose output will be a list representing the image of a given subset under the function. I'm expecting it to look like this in the end:

```
(image '(1 2 3)  '((5 4) (3 4) (1 4) (2 6))) ----> (6 4)
```

So far I've written something that looks like this:

```
(define (image subset-of-domain func-pairs)
   (cond
     ((empty? (first subset-of-domain))
            (null))
     ((equal? (first subset-of-domain) (first (first func-pairs)))
            (rest (first func-pairs))) (else (image (rest subset-of-domain) (rest func-pairs)))))
```

From those inputs, the output of image should be a list representing the image of that given subset under that function. Also, I want to remove any duplicates so that a number only shows up once (Hence why the example result is (6 4) and not (4 6 4).

Thanks, I've been stuck on this for a while now. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to roll your own filter/map helper procedure in terms of basic list functions and then remove the duplicates:

```
(define (image subset-of-domain func-pairs)
  (define (image-helper lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) '())
          ((member (caar lst) subset-of-domain)
           (cons (cadar lst) (image-helper (cdr lst))))
          (else (image-helper (cdr lst)))))
  (remove-duplicates (image-helper func-pairs)))
```

The above will work fine, but it's not recommended - basically, we would be reinventing the wheel. A much more idiomatic solution would be to use (mostly) standard higher-order procedures:

```
(define (image subset-of-domain func-pairs)
  (remove-duplicates
   (map cadr
        (filter (lambda (pair)
                  (member (car pair) subset-of-domain))
                func-pairs))))
```

If your interpreter doesn't provide a `remove-duplicates` function, it's [easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20084810/201359) to [implement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21299365/201359) [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17433811/201359). Even better, if your interpreter happens to be Racket we can write a shorter solution just by using built-in procedures:

```
(define (image subset-of-domain func-pairs)
  (remove-duplicates
   (filter-map (lambda (pair)
                 (and (member (first pair) subset-of-domain)
                      (second pair)))
               func-pairs)))
```